# Set background width (of img) to 'cover' in JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm looking for a way to set the width of my image to 'cover' *(in CSS: background-size: cover;)*.

There are some lib's out there so that you can use CSS in your jsx file, however, I'd like to avoid that.

E.g. having the image covering the whole row:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parent to that `<img/>` like that.

JSX:

```
<div className="img-container">
   <img src={image}/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh; // or how much you want
}

.img-container img{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this in the image tag:

style={{backgroundSize:"cover"}}

JSX has a different parser than css so replace all '-' with camelcase when styling